# Convert Decimal or RGB color code to HTML (Hex) code

Tags: html, vba, colors, hex, rgb

How do I convert a VBA (or VB) Decimal or RGB colour code to an HTML (Hex) color code using VBA or on an Excel worksheet?

Examples:

```
INPUT:         OUTPUT:
123456         #40E201
vbRed          #FF0000
(48, 151, 62)  #30973E
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following VBA function converts a **Decimal Color Code** (`0` to `16777215`) to a hexadecimal HTML color code (`#000000` to `#FFFFFF`):

```
Function Dec2HexColor(decColor As Long) As String
    If decColor > 16777215 Then decColor = 16777215
    If decColor < 0 Then decColor = 0
    Dec2HexColor = "#" & Right("00" & Hex((decColor Mod 256)), 2) & _
                         Right("00" & Hex((decColor \ 256) Mod 256), 2) & _
                         Right("00" & Hex(decColor \ 65536), 2)
End Function
```

It can also be used with a set a of **RGB color values** (Red, Green, Blue; each `0` to `255`) by combining it with VBA's `RGB` function as shown below.

**Examples:**

```
Sub test()
    Debug.Print Dec2HexColor(vbRed)              'returns: "#FF0000"
    Debug.Print Dec2HexColor(vbGreen)            'returns: "#00FF00"
    Debug.Print Dec2HexColor(vbMagenta)          'returns: "#FF00FF"
    Debug.Print Dec2HexColor(12345678)           'returns: "#4E61BC"
    Debug.Print Dec2HexColor(0)                  'returns: "#000000"
    Debug.Print Dec2HexColor(RGB(255, 0, 0))     'returns: "#FF0000"
    Debug.Print Dec2HexColor(RGB(48, 151, 62))   'returns: "#30973E"
End Sub
```